# call a .csh file from .sh file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, centos, csh

Can I call a `.csh` script file from `.sh` shell script file?

For example, I have `a.sh`, `b.csh`. Can I call b.csh in a.sh file? If so, how?

I have tried writing this is ash file

1. `variable= source /path/to/b.csh` - Didn't work
2. `sh ./path/to/b.csh` - didn't work

I would like to add by saying that the `b.csh` file has shebang line mentioned as `#!/bin/csh -fx`

Comment: You can't source it because that makes the original a.sh shell read it. You can't demand that sh runs it because sh does not understand csh syntax. But if b.csh has execute permissions and a shebang and is on your path, you can just run it as `b.sh`. No need to complicate it.

Comment: You probably want `variable=$( /path/to/b.csh )` if you want to store its stdout into a variable in a.sh.

Comment: I  would like to add by saying that even b.csh file has shebang line mentioned as #!/bin/csh -fx    so can I call b.csh file from a.sh as b.sh ?

Comment: No. The file extension contains no magic whatsoever: it's just part of the filename. If you try to execute `b.sh`, you'll get a "not found" error (unless b.sh actually exists, in which case you are not executing b.csh)

Comment: So what should I do if I want to call b.csh but can't call it or invoke it from a.sh file,  what is the alternative so that I can achieve this task?

Comment: I do not understand: you want to call it but you can't call it. Please edit your question to add additional details about your constraints. Also, what do you mean by "call"?

Comment: Call meaning executing the script(b.csh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *execute* `b.csh` from `a.sh`, just as you can execute any program like `grep` or `cat`.

You cannot expect that executing `b.csh` will add any variables to the environment of the shell running `a.sh` -- b.csh will run in a child process, and a child process is not allowed to alter the environment of the parent process (this is basic security).

If you need to communicate data from `b.csh`, then b.csh needs to *print* that data, and a.sh can capture it with command substitution: `data=$(b.csh)` -- although you'll probably have to remove the `-x` option from the csh shebang line to reduce the noise.

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
./script.sh
```

You are telling your shell that it should run the script `./script.sh`. But the shell does not know how should `./script.sh` be run. Is it a `bash` script? Maybe it is `csh`? Or perhaps it is a binary ELF file, like `ls`? Or maybe a `python` script. To know it, the OS will look at the first bytes of the file. If it finds a shebang, that means that it should handle that file to the program specified in the shebang.

So, if the first line of your script is

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
...
```

It will handle the file to a program named `bash` in the directory `/usr/bin`, efectively doing `bash ./script.sh`.

But if you write `sh ./path/to/b.csh`, you are directly handling the file to a program named `sh`. `sh` will ignore the first line, since it happens that it interprets lines begining with `#` as comments.

So, you should not write `sh ./path/to/b.csh`, but `./path/to/b.csh` if you want the shebang to be honored.

Note that this will spawn a new process to run the script. If you want to run each line in `./path/to/b.csh` like if it was writen directly in `a.sh`, you should instead do `source ./path/to/b.csh` (or `. ./path/to/b.csh`, to be portable). But it will also ignore the shebang, and each line will be evaluated like a `sh` command, not like a `csh` one.